# Configure folder inside application as another application in IIS

Tags: iis, authentication

HI,

my main application uses windows authentication, i have it configured as 
"Integrated windows authentication" and "basic authentication" in IIS

i also have a folder "register" which i have also configured as application, and set properties to: "enable anonymour access" and "integrated windows authentication"

i put another web config in my register folder, and set authentication to forms:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

so now when i go to my website/register it still asks me for my username and password, but when i cancel it shows the registration form... so thats fine. but how do i get it to not pop up the username / password window?